# Fama Macbeth Regression in Python (Pandas or Statsmodels)

Tags: python, r, pandas, statsmodels

***Econometric Backgroud***

Fama Macbeth regression refers to a procedure to run regression for panel data (where there are N different individuals and each individual corresponds to multiple periods T, e.g. day, months,year). So in total there are N x T obs. Notice it's OK if the panel data is not balanced.

The Fama Macbeth regression is to first run regression for each period cross-sectinally, i.e. pool N individuals together in a given period t. And do this for t=1,...T. So in total T regressions are run. Then we have a time series of coefficients for each independent variable. Then we can perform hypothesis test using the time series of coefficients. Usually we take the average as the final coefficients of each independent variable. And we use t-stats to test significance.

***My Problem***

My problem is to implement this in pandas. From the source code of pandas, I noticed there is a procedure called `fama_macbeth`. But I can't find any documentation about this.

The operation can be easily done through `groupby` as well. Currently I am doing this:

```
def fmreg(data,formula):
    return smf.ols(formula,data=data).fit().params[1]

res=df.groupby('date').apply(fmreg,'ret~var1')
```

This works, `res` is a Series which is indexed by `date` and the values of Series are `params[1]`, which is the coefficient of `var1`. But now I want to have more independent variables, I need to extract the coefficients of all these independent variables, but I can't figure that out. I tried this

```
def fmreg(data,formula):
    return smf.ols(formula,data=data).fit().params

res=df.groupby('date').apply(fmreg,'ret~var1+var2+var3')
```

This won't work. The desired result is that `res` is a dataframe indexed by `date`, and each column of the dataframe should contain the coefficients of each variable `intercept`, `var1`, `var2` and `var3`.

I also checked with `statsmodels`, they don't have such built-in procedure as well.

And is there any package that can produce publication-quality regression tables? Like `outreg2` in Stata and `texreg` in R?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: to the last part of the question: statsmodels has a `summary_col` function but it is missing some options (and bells and whistles) https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1637

Comment: Thanks! But it seems very rough, and not nearly as neat as R's `texreg` or stata's `outreg2`. I guess I will have to switch to R for output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An update to reflect the library situation for Fama-MacBeth as of Fall 2018. The `fama_macbeth` function has been removed from `pandas` for a while now. So what are your options?

1. If you're using python 3, then you can use the Fama-MacBeth method in LinearModels: https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/blob/master/linearmodels/panel/model.py
2. If you're using python 2 or just don't want to use LinearModels, then probably your best option is to roll you own.

For example, suppose you have the Fama-French industry portfolios in a panel like the following (you've also computed some variables like past beta or past returns to use as your x-variables):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('industry.csv',parse_dates=['caldt'])
        df.query("caldt == '1995-07-01'")

In [5]: Out[5]: 
      industry      caldt    ret    beta  r12to2  r36to13
18432     Aero 1995-07-01   6.26  0.9696  0.2755   0.3466
18433    Agric 1995-07-01   3.37  1.0412  0.1260   0.0581
18434    Autos 1995-07-01   2.42  1.0274  0.0293   0.2902
18435    Banks 1995-07-01   4.82  1.4985  0.1659   0.2951
```

Fama-MacBeth primarily involves computing the same cross-sectional regression model month by month, so you can implement it using a `groupby`. You can create a function that takes a `dataframe` (it will come from the `groupby`) and a `patsy` formula; it then fits the model and returns the parameter estimates. Here is a barebones version of how you could implement it (note this is what the original questioner tried to do a few years ago ... not sure why it didn't work although it's possible back then `statsmodels` result object method `params` wasn't returning a `pandas` `Series` so the return needed to be converted to a `Series` explicitly ... it does work fine in the current version of `pandas`, 0.23.4):

```
def ols_coef(x,formula):
    return smf.ols(formula,data=x).fit().params

In [9]: gamma = (df.groupby('caldt')
                .apply(ols_coef,'ret ~ 1 + beta + r12to2 + r36to13'))
        gamma.head()

In [10]: Out[10]: 
            Intercept      beta     r12to2   r36to13
caldt                                               
1963-07-01  -1.497012 -0.765721   4.379128 -1.918083
1963-08-01  11.144169 -6.506291   5.961584 -2.598048
1963-09-01  -2.330966 -0.741550  10.508617 -4.377293
1963-10-01   0.441941  1.127567   5.478114 -2.057173
1963-11-01   3.380485 -4.792643   3.660940 -1.210426
```

Then just compute the mean, standard error on the mean, and a t-test (or whatever statistics you want). Something like the following:

```
def fm_summary(p):
    s = p.describe().T
    s['std_error'] = s['std']/np.sqrt(s['count'])
    s['tstat'] = s['mean']/s['std_error']
    return s[['mean','std_error','tstat']]

In [12]: fm_summary(gamma)
Out[12]: 
               mean  std_error     tstat
Intercept  0.754904   0.177291  4.258000
beta      -0.012176   0.202629 -0.060092
r12to2     1.794548   0.356069  5.039896
r36to13    0.237873   0.186680  1.274230
```

**Improving Speed**

Using `statsmodels` for the regressions has significant overhead (particularly given you only need the estimated coefficients). If you want better efficiency, then you could switch from `statsmodels` to `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. Write a new function that does the ols estimation ... something like the following (notice I'm not doing anything like checking the rank of these matrices ...):

```
def ols_np(data,yvar,xvar):
    gamma,_,_,_ = np.linalg.lstsq(data[xvar],data[yvar],rcond=None)
    return pd.Series(gamma)
```

And if you're still using an older version of `pandas`, the following will work:

Here is an example of using the `fama_macbeth` function in `pandas`:

```
>>> df

                y    x
date       id
2012-01-01 1   0.1  0.4
           2   0.3  0.6
           3   0.4  0.2
           4   0.0  1.2
2012-02-01 1   0.2  0.7
           2   0.4  0.5
           3   0.2  0.1
           4   0.1  0.0
2012-03-01 1   0.4  0.8
           2   0.6  0.1
           3   0.7  0.6
           4   0.4 -0.1
```

Notice, the structure. The `fama_macbeth` function expects the y-var and x-vars to have a multi-index with date as the first variable and the stock/firm/entity id as the second variable in the index:

```
>>> fm  = pd.fama_macbeth(y=df['y'],x=df[['x']])
>>> fm


----------------------Summary of Fama-MacBeth Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ x + intercept
# betas :   3

----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
     Variable          Beta       Std Err        t-stat       CI 2.5%      CI 97.5%
          (x)       -0.0227        0.1276         -0.18       -0.2728        0.2273
  (intercept)        0.3531        0.0842          4.19        0.1881        0.5181

--------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Note that just printing `fm` calls fm.summary

```
>>> fm.summary

----------------------Summary of Fama-MacBeth Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ x + intercept
# betas :   3

----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
     Variable          Beta       Std Err        t-stat       CI 2.5%      CI 97.5%
          (x)       -0.0227        0.1276         -0.18       -0.2728        0.2273
  (intercept)        0.3531        0.0842          4.19        0.1881        0.5181

--------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Also, note the `fama_macbeth` function automatically adds an intercept (as opposed to `statsmodels` routines). Also the x-var has to be a `dataframe` so if you pass just one column you need to pass it as `df[['x']]`.

If you don't want an intercept you have to do:

```
>>> fm  = pd.fama_macbeth(y=df['y'],x=df[['x']],intercept=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant move it to `statsmodels`.

Comment: Do you care to show me how to manually do this in `groupby`, namely, what mistake did I make in second part of my own code?

Comment: My statsmodels are up-to-date. I want to keep each coefficient as different columns in a row, which should be indexed by `date`. I will try to add `pd.Series` and see if it works

Comment: Your code works for my simple example: `res = df.groupby('date').apply(fmreg,'y~1+x')`. It also work fine when I add another x-variable: `df.groupby('date').apply(fmreg,'y~x + x2')`.

Comment: Right, I get exactly your desired output with no real modification of your code. Not sure I can really help unless you show a small reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: The dataframe must have a multiIndex, where time as level 0 and id as level 1?

Comment: And my time index is quarters. I got this error 

`freq not specified and cannot be inferred from first element` Do you know how do I specify frequency? I tried to add `freq='Q'`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Is it specified as a `DateTimeIndex`? the `fama_macbeth` function doesn't required a regular frequency but it does require the level_0 be a `DateTimeIndex`

Comment: It's a `period index`

Comment: Not sure then. You may want to try switching to a `Datetimeindex`, but a `PeriodIndex` does work for me. Otherwise, you might try to boil it down to a small example and start a new question.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: New Library**

An updated library exists which can be installed via the following command:

```
pip install finance-byu
```

Documentation here: https://fin-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The new library includes Fama Macbeth regression implementations and a `Regtable` class that can be helpful for reporting results.

This page in the documentation outlines the Fama Macbeth functions: https://fin-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fama_macbeth.html

There is an implementation which is very similar to Karl D.'s implementation above with `numpy`'s linear algebra functions, an implementation that utilizes `joblib` for parallelization to increase performance when a large number of time periods in the data, and an implementation using `numba` for optimization that shaves off an order of magnitude on small data sets.

Here is an example with a small simulated data set as in the documentation:

```
>>> from finance_byu.fama_macbeth import fama_macbeth, fama_macbeth_parallel, fm_summary, fama_macbeth_numba
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import time
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> n_jobs = 5
>>> n_firms = 1.0e2
>>> n_periods = 1.0e2
>>> 
>>> def firm(fid):
>>>     f = np.random.random((int(n_periods),4))
>>>     f = pd.DataFrame(f)
>>>     f['period'] = f.index
>>>     f['firmid'] = fid
>>>     return f
>>> df = [firm(i) for i in range(int(n_firms))]
>>> df = pd.concat(df).rename(columns={0:'ret',1:'exmkt',2:'smb',3:'hml'})
>>> df.head()

        ret     exmkt       smb       hml  period  firmid
0  0.766593  0.002390  0.496230  0.992345       0       0
1  0.346250  0.509880  0.083644  0.732374       1       0
2  0.787731  0.204211  0.705075  0.313182       2       0
3  0.904969  0.338722  0.437298  0.669285       3       0
4  0.121908  0.827623  0.319610  0.455530       4       0

>>> result = fama_macbeth(df,'period','ret',['exmkt','smb','hml'],intercept=True)
>>> result.head()

        intercept     exmkt       smb       hml
period                                         
0        0.655784 -0.160938 -0.109336  0.028015
1        0.455177  0.033941  0.085344  0.013814
2        0.410705 -0.084130  0.218568  0.016897
3        0.410537  0.010719  0.208912  0.001029
4        0.439061  0.046104 -0.084381  0.199775

>>> fm_summary(result)

               mean  std_error      tstat
intercept  0.506834   0.008793  57.643021
exmkt      0.004750   0.009828   0.483269
smb       -0.012702   0.010842  -1.171530
hml        0.004276   0.010530   0.406119

>>> %timeit fama_macbeth(df,'period','ret',['exmkt','smb','hml'],intercept=True)
123 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each  
>>> %timeit fama_macbeth_parallel(df,'period','ret',['exmkt','smb','hml'],intercept=True,n_jobs=n_jobs,memmap=False)  
146 ms ± 16.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> %timeit fama_macbeth_numba(df,'period','ret',['exmkt','smb','hml'],intercept=True)
5.04 ms ± 5.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note: Turning off the memmap makes for fair comparison without generating new data at each run. With the memmap, the parallel implementation would simply pull cached results.

Here are a couple simple implementations of the table class also using simulated data:

```
>>> from finance_byu.regtables import Regtable
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> 
>>> nobs = 1000
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((nobs,3))).rename(columns={0:'age',1:'bmi',2:'hincome'})
>>> df['age'] = df['age']*100
>>> df['bmi'] = df['bmi']*30
>>> df['hincome'] = df['hincome']*100000
>>> df['hincome'] = pd.qcut(df['hincome'],16,labels=False)
>>> df['rich'] = df['hincome'] > 13
>>> df['gender'] = np.random.choice(['M','F'],nobs)
>>> df['race'] = np.random.choice(['W','B','H','O'],nobs)
>>> 
>>> regformulas =  ['bmi ~ age',
>>>                 'bmi ~ np.log(age)',
>>>                 'bmi ~ C(gender) + np.log(age)',
>>>                 'bmi ~ C(gender) + C(race) + np.log(age)',
>>>                 'bmi ~ C(gender) + rich + C(gender)*rich + C(race) + np.log(age)',
>>>                 'bmi ~ -1 + np.log(age)',
>>>                 'bmi ~ -1 + C(race) + np.log(age)']
>>> reg = [smf.ols(f,df).fit() for f in regformulas]
>>> tbl = Regtable(reg)
>>> tbl.render()
```

Produces the following:
[image]

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((nobs,10)))
>>> df2.columns = ['t0_vw','t4_vw','et_vw','t0_ew','t4_ew','et_ew','mktrf','smb','hml','umd']
>>> regformulas2 = ['t0_vw ~ mktrf',
>>>                't0_vw ~ mktrf + smb + hml',
>>>                't0_vw ~ mktrf + smb + hml + umd',
>>>                't4_vw ~ mktrf',
>>>                't4_vw ~ mktrf + smb + hml',
>>>                't4_vw ~ mktrf + smb + hml + umd',
>>>                'et_vw ~ mktrf',
>>>                'et_vw ~ mktrf + smb + hml',
>>>                'et_vw ~ mktrf + smb + hml + umd',
>>>                't0_ew ~ mktrf',
>>>                't0_ew ~ mktrf + smb + hml',
>>>                't0_ew ~ mktrf + smb + hml + umd',
>>>                't4_ew ~ mktrf',
>>>                't4_ew ~ mktrf + smb + hml',
>>>                't4_ew ~ mktrf + smb + hml + umd',
>>>                'et_ew ~ mktrf',
>>>                'et_ew ~ mktrf + smb + hml',
>>>                'et_ew ~ mktrf + smb + hml + umd'
>>>                ]
>>> regnames = ['Small VW','','',
>>>             'Large VW','','',
>>>             'Spread VW','','',
>>>             'Small EW','','',
>>>             'Large EW','','',
>>>             'Spread EW','',''
>>>             ]
>>> reg2 = [smf.ols(f,df2).fit() for f in regformulas2]
>>> 
>>> tbl2 = Regtable(reg2,orientation='horizontal',regnames=regnames,sig='coeff',intercept_name='alpha',nobs=False,rsq=False,stat='se')
>>> tbl2.render()
```

Produces the following:

[image]

The documentation for the Regtable class is here: https://byu-finance-library-finance-byu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/regtables.html

These tables can be exported to LaTeX for easy incorporation into writing:

```
tbl.to_latex()
```

Comment: Are these byu links still alive?

Comment: @Martien I just updated the links and install info. The documentation moved to a new location on readthedocs and migrated from test PyPi to normal PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution to solve the problem and continue using the same thing you were using.

It worked for me.

```py
def fmreg(data,formula):
    return smf.ols(formula,data=data).fit().params[:]

res = df.groupby('date').apply(fmreg,'ret~var1+var2+var3')
```