# Fama-Macbeth in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels

First of all, I am very new to Python, so I am not as technically gifted in programming. However, I am running a `Fama-Macbeth` regression to estimate risk premia of different macroeconomic variables. Similarly to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074481/fama-macbeth-regression-in-python-pandas-or-statsmodels).

My problem is that `fama_macbeth` seems to have depreciated in `pandas`, and moved to statsmodels which I find more confusing.

My data:
I have time series of *S&P index returns*, as well as different variables i.e. industry production, *gdp, cpi* etc. (Monthly data for approx. 20 years)

What I wish to do is:
Regress the index returns on all the variables i.e. y= bx(1) + bx(2) + bx(3), and save the coefficients for each variables as a new time series, which I can regress the index return on in the second part of the analysis.

Anyone have an idea of how to use the `fama_macbeth` in `statsmodels` in my case, or any other approaches to my problem. If anyone has a source where a similar project has been shared it would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to find previous examples of this approach in *Python* anywhere.

Comment: Share some code that you have already tried.

Comment: You can also check the library [here](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/models.html#linearmodels.panel.model.FamaMacBeth)

Comment: My problem is that I am completely blank on the matter, so I hoped to get an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: fama_macbeth is not in statsmodels, look at Evgeny's link

Comment: When I try:

from linearmodels import FamaMacBeth

mod = FamaMacBeth(df['VW'], df['cpi'])

res = mod.fit(cov_type='kernel', kernel='Parzen')

I get the error:"Series can only be used with a 2-level MultiIndex"