# PatsyError when using statsmodels for regression

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `ols` in `statsmodels` to run a regression. Once I run the regressions on each row of my dataframe, I want to retrieve the X variables from `patsy` thats used in those regressions. But, I get an error that I just cant seem to understand.

**Edit**: I am trying to run a regression as presented in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074481/fama-macbeth-regression-in-python-pandas-or-statsmodels), but want to run the regression across each row of a grouped version of my dataframe `df`, where it is grouped by `Date`,`bal`, `dist`, `pay_hist`, `inc`, `bckts`. So I first group this data as described above and then try to run the regression on each row where `df` is grouped by `Date`: `df.groupby(['Date']).apply(ols_coef,'bal ~ C(dist)  + C(pay_hist) + C(inc) + C(bckts)')`

My code is as follows:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

df = df.groupby([['Date','bal', 'dist', 'pay_hist', 'inc', 'bckts']])

######run regression
def ols_coef(x,formula):

    return ols(formula,data=x).fit().params

gamma = df.groupby(['Date']).apply(ols_coef,'bal ~ C(dist)  + C(pay_hist) + C(inc) + C(bckts)')
print('gamme is {}'.format(gamma))
########################

#####Now trying to retrieve the X variables in the regressions above
formula = 'bal ~ C(dist)  + C(pay_hist) + C(inc) + C(bckts)'
data = df.groupby(['Date'])[['bckts', 'wac_dist', 'pay_hist', 'inc', 'bal']]
y,X = patsy.dmatrices(formula,data,return_type='dataframe')
################
```

I get the following error and am unsure how to solve it:

```
patsy.PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: Exception: Column(s) ['bckts', 'dist', 'pay_hist', 'inc', 'bal'] already selected
    bal ~ C(dist)  + C(pay_hist) + C(inc) + C(bckts)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ```df.apply``` applies column-wise not row-wise. You also need to be clear about why you're grouping by 'Date', what is your objective with that? Do you want to run separate regressions for each 'Date' group in your dataframe? It's uncommon to just groupby 'date', usually you would have 'month' or 'year' or something along those lines..

Comment: @annicheez Thanks. I am running the regression as is presented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074481/fama-macbeth-regression-in-python-pandas-or-statsmodels). I changed the question to reflect the fact that I first groupby `Date`, `bal`, etc and want to run the regression on the rows that reflect that grouped data. Also the `date` is monthly so its effectively a month

Comment: thanks for the info. See my answer below. The problem is that you feeding a grouped data frame into the ```pasty.dmatrices``` function, which throws an error because it expects one instance of the Xs and Y columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a grouped dataframe into the`pasty.dmatrices` function. Since the grouped dataframe is iterable, you can do it in a loop like this, and store all of your X dataframs (one for each group) into a dictionary:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import patsy

# Loading data
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data

# Extracting Independent variables
formula = 'Suicides ~ Crime_parents + Infanticide'
data = df.groupby(['Region'])[['Suicides', 'Crime_parents', 'Infanticide', 'Region']]
X = {}
for name, group in data: 
    Y, X[name] = patsy.dmatrices(formula, group, return_type='dataframe')

print(X)
```